# New Facebook App required for every environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-login

I managed to add 'Facebook Login' functionality to my Ruby on Rails project and it works well with the Site URL pointing to my local development environment (e.g, http://www.dev.project.com:3000). However, when pushing my code to the production server, the Site URL set in the Facebook App has to be changed accordingly (e.g., http://www.project.com). After that, the Facebook Login works for the production environment, but not anymore in my local development environment.

In other words, is it possible to specify multiple Site URLs for a single Facebook App, or do I really have to create a new Facebook App for every development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays you can add multiple domains for your Facebook application. This should solve this issue.

Comment: Adding the domain to "App Domain" really seems to do the trick. But what is the purpose of the Site URL then?

Comment: Which Site URL are you refering to? Maybe it's for Facebook Connect?

Comment: The *Site URL* is the "Website with Facebook Login" Site URL. It's the *"URL for your website. For security reasons, [Facebook] will only redirect to this URL [when logging in via OAuth I think]"* .